# How to make the URL of $resource generic?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am new to AngularJS and I have a question here.

I am using `$resource` for my CRUD actions.

I currently have the code like this,

```
angular.module("dopAngular.services")
.factory("UserRoleService", ["$resource",
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource("api/UserRoleApi", {}, {
            query: { method: "GET", isArray: true },
            create: { method: "POST" },
            get: { method: "GET" },
            remove: { method: "DELETE" },
            update: { method: "PUT" }
        });

    }]);

    //below is the code in my controller
              UserRoleService.query(function (data) {
                vm.UserRoleLookups = data;
            });
```

I would like to make my `UserRoleService` generic, which means I don't want to provide the specific URL for the API in the factory level.

I now modify my code a little bit,

```
angular.module("dopAngular.services")
.factory("UserRoleService", ["$resource",
    function ($resource, url) {
        return $resource(url, {}, {
            query: { method: "GET", isArray: true },
            create: { method: "POST" },
            get: { method: "GET" },
            remove: { method: "DELETE" },
            update: { method: "PUT" }
        });

    }]);
```

My question is what I should do in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of directly returning `$resource`, we can encapsulate it with a function that accepts `url` as a param.

Something like this:

```
myApp.factory('UserRoleService', function($resource) {
  return {
    query: function(url) {
      return $resource(url, {}, {
        query: {
          method: "GET",
          isArray: true
        },
        get: {
          method: "GET"
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Now, in controller, you can call it like:

```
UserRoleService.query('//httpbin.org').get()
```

[**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cndnjf3v/2/)